# windows batch multiline command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

Can someone please tell me what in the following command line not correct is?

```
${WORKSPACE} = C:\jenkins\workspace\compile-job

cmd.exe /s /c START /b /BELOWNORMAL
mkdir C:\jenkins\workspace\old
move /Y %WORKSPACE%\* C:\jenkins\workspace\old
rmdir /q /s C:\jenkins\workspace\old
```

Comment: Does it work for you as expected?

Comment: %WORKSPACE%\* its not possible, because it can not move all folders?
* this is the problem

Comment: i think I need a loop for all folders...

Comment: You have more pressing problems, I guess, as this will certainly not do what you intended (or your intentions are very weird).

Answer (score 1):

Plenty.

1. `${WORKSPACE} = ...` is neither `cmd` nor PowerShell syntax, it's nothing sensible. Use

   ```
   set WORKSPACE=C:\jenkins\workspace\compile-job
   ```

   instead.
2. You can have multi-line commands by ending the line before with `^`. However you want to execute three commands instead of just one. One option would be to write a batch file to execute (certainly the cleanest approach). But since you already have one, you can get clever:

   ```
   if not %1==x (
     START "" /b /BELOWNORMAL %0 x
     goto :eof
   )

   set WORKSPACE=C:\jenkins\workspace\compile-job

   mkdir C:\jenkins\workspace\old
   move /Y %WORKSPACE%\* C:\jenkins\workspace\old
   rmdir /q /s C:\jenkins\workspace\old
   ```

   This will execute the batch file again but with an argument and within the batch we look whether that argument is present and do the work or not.

Comment: the set is not in use, ${WORKSPACE} is a env variable from Jenkins...
if not %1==x will not work with Jenkins Windows Batch... I want after each job, in background workspace moven and delete

Comment: The process can not move the files because it is being used by another process. Jenkins process is running... cmd can not move the files. has anyone idea/solution?